# Nuget an error occurred while trying to restore packages. A local file header is corrupted

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

i have a project in visual studio 2015 when i try to restore the packages from nuget i am getting issue that is describing "an error occurred while trying to restore packages. A local file header is corrupted". I am attaching the Picture that i am getting in visual studio 2015.[image]

What is the solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have try 2 days to resolve this issue using google. At Last i get one solution form Leo Liu-MSFT in his answer [Answer by Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279660/nuget-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-restore-packages-a-local-file-header-is/49292341#49292341). I also try this solution but Liu answer provide me the basic concept something is an error in my Nuget that i need to fix. After that i reinstall Visual Studio 2015 again and start the visual studio and restore packages and it works perfectly. I hope my answer will help someone to save time.

Answer (score 1):

> Nuget an error occurred while trying to restore packages. A local file header is corrupted

It seems that nuget cache can be somewhat corrupted, so please try to use this command to clear all caches:

```
 nuget locals all -clear
```

Then restore your nuget packages again.

If it not help you, try to close the Visual Studio, then delete the `NuGet.Config` file (Backup it if there is a need) from this folder:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
```

Then reopen your project, restore the nuget packages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Leo Liu-MSFT sorry for late reply. I tried this but this solution not worked for me. After that i reinstall Visual Studio 2015 after that it start working in project.

Comment: i have posted my answer. Hope someone save there time to resolve this issue

Comment: thanks, Hope it help some one save time that i have expend 2 days to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with VS 2022 and it happened to be a corrupted Infragistics nuget package, which are stored locally on the machine. The error was extremely vague until I removed all nuget packages and started to re add them one by one with the package manager. Once I got to an Infragistics package the nuget window showed a detailed error with the corrupted file name. Fortunately for me it was an older package version causing the problem, I deleted it and then nuget had no problem finding the version I was actually referencing.